# Knn imputation using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, imputation

I am trying to impute missing values in my dataset by using Knn.
Could anyone suggest me a concept of this method and how to do this by using Knn in scikit-learn.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to use knn without even understanding what it is?

Comment: 1) Do you understand what imputation is?
2) Do you understand what K-nearest neighbours achieves?
3) If you don't understand `No. 2` then look into clustering algorithms
4) Think about clusters that group similar collections can be appropriate for filling in missing data (with possibly similar features instead of a uniform one)
5) do steps 1 to 4 and repeat until you understand.

Comment: For me, I think knn imputation will find value of the nearest row (or column?) of missing value and use this value to impute in the particular missing value.

Comment: Essentially, that is the idea. May  I suggest you follow this [chat on github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2989) and some of the links to references for knn imputations.

Comment: If you're willing to switch to R, you can use the [imputation package](https://github.com/alexwhitworth/imputation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use KNN imputer from Sklearn, 
Note: works only on numerical data not on categorical, I know because I tried on categorical

> > > import numpy as np
> > >
> > > from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
> > >
> > > X = [[1, 2, np.nan], [3, 4, 3], [np.nan, 6, 5], [8, 8, 7]]
> > >
> > > imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2)
> > >
> > > imputer.fit_transform(X)

please go to [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html) for more info